# Moto G6 device not found after rooting process

Tags: android, root

My goal is to get my Moto G6 phone in Root Mode. I bought a blank phone for this purpose, so no data is at risk. After following the steps on the XDA guide, I only got so before things did not work as they described. If I reboot my phone, I get this blue Moto G6 bootscreen and the phone never boots. I can get TWRP running on the phone though.  Right now, my phone is not being recognized by either adb or fastboot. The guide I've been following is at

https://forum.xda-developers.com/moto-g6/how-to/guide-twrp-root-magisk-installation-t3816569

```
c:\Software\MotoG6>adb shell
error: no devices/emulators found
c:\Software\MotoG6>fastboot devices

c:\Software\MotoG6>
```

I have the latest Moto G6 drivers installed, but I don't think they apply anymore. If I unplug and replug in the USB cable into my Windows machine, it says it does not recognize the device.

The firmware I saw on the device when it did boot was OPSS27.82-87

***  I do not know how to go back to stock because it won't recognize the device enough for me to push the stock image to it. ***

*** FWIW, even on step 3 of that guide, it would say the boot image was not signed or corrupt. This happened when I tried to do

```
fastboot flash boot <insert-boot-image-name-here>.img
```

someone else had that problem and the recommendation was to ignore the message and reboot to recovery.

(https://forum.xda-developers.com/moto-g4-plus/development/wip-twrp-3-0-2-2-recovery-moto-g4-plus-t3386586/page2)

For those who would say, "Read the **** manual", bear in mind that I did read the manual. No manual said where to get the firmware information they asked for. Also, many of the image links were bad. They did not say how to handle the case where the image did not install as they said it would.  Somehow these manufacturers make each phone just enough different, and each firmware is different that it's impossible to predict what a phone will say ahead of time with certainty.

Comment: check the adb driver

Comment: @indralesmana how do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

When it shows no commands, press and hold the power button then tap volume up button once. Then release the power button.

If this doesn't work mostly likely needs to be sent back to the manufacturer.